# how use plugin jquery and jquery plugins in framework7

Tags: jquery, html-framework-7

I am trying to use jquery-qrcode in framework7 project, but throw error " '$' is not defined." 
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please include your code in the question itself, rather than as screenshots. It makes it easier for people to help you. To fix your issue, you need to put the `<script>` line for your javascript after the jquery ones.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you can do one of these way:

1) you can include jquery script in `<head>` tag before include a framework7 like this:

```
<!-- Path to Jquery Library JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/f7/framework7.min.js"></script>
```

This snippet from real project code....

2) you can include jquery and  jquery-qrcode in your appjs file or any js file you need in project by using import like this:

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
```

by this syntax your $ will be defined, so that you can next of this line include jquery qr by something like this:

```
import * as qrCode from 'qrcode-jquery';
```

Notes: make sure to use real plugin/file name nested of qrcode-jquery(this name just an example), also if you use first method make sure to put qrcode plugin after jquery plugin.....